# Code changes borders in a diagonale, however other cells change as well once value is pasted in?

Tags: excel, vba

I have come across a weird problem in the formatting section of my code.
Code function:
The code should identify a matrix and cross out the diagonal cells with two diagonal border lines. Once the sub runs, it works fine and does exactly that.
[image: BEFORE]

However, when i start putting values into the matrix' cells, at some point, once i have filled a critical amount of cells, the cells i put values in start change their borders as the cells of the diagonal did!?
[image]

Can anyone help?

Below I have recreated the problem:

```
Sub Formatting()

With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells
    .ClearContents
    .Cells.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Cells.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
End With

Dim xCol As Long, xRow As Long
Dim xColDiag As Long, xRowDiag As Long

xCol = 2
xRow = 3
xColDiag = 3
xRowDiag = 3

Do Until xColDiag > 9

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(xRowDiag, xColDiag)
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .FormatConditions.Delete
    End With

    xRowDiag = xRowDiag + 1
    xColDiag = xColDiag + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: How does your code get run, you manually run the sub, is it invoked by a button, or perhaps triggered by a worksheet event?

Comment: Hi Luuklag, the code is initated by pressing a commandbutton on a worksheet.

Comment: You're not copying and pasting? I can't replicate that - you could remove all borders at the start of your code before adding the ones you want?

Comment: @SJR, type in x for every cell manually (as that is what the user of my program would do eventually), then you should see the issue. I have also included a few lines that clear all previous formatting and borders (edit above).

Comment: I take it back. I think you can solve this by turning off "extend data range formats" in Excel options/Advanced.

Comment: I dont believe it, amazing haha! Such an easy fix yet so hard to solve if you dont know about it! @ SJR Thanks so much!